# "Doctors often work very long hours": intransitive verb followed by a noun?

Tags: intransitive-verbs, grammatical-roles, measure-phrases

I spotted something iffy in "work".

[Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/work_1?q=work) has

> A1: [intransitive]
>
> - noun Doctors often work very long hours.

[Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/230217) has

> b. intransitive. With adverb or noun phrase denoting the length of
> time or pattern of work.
>
> 1967 Jrnl. Pediatrics 70 642/1   He had a butcher shop and worked long
> hours.

We also say "work night shifts".

I thought an intransitive verb cannot be followed by a noun. Otherwise it's called a transitive verb.

When "work" has the intransitive meaning, why can a noun follow? Why don't the dictionaries just say it's transitive?

Some references will be awesome.

Comment: You can *work the crowd* transivitively, but when you work night shifts, you're working at night (adverbial.)

Comment: Hello, Gqqnbig. I sympathise. I've looked at different English analyses on the nature of a direct object, and I believe that different grammarians have decided on different explanations for trickier cases (eg 'The harpsichord is selling as a single piece of furniture, but _the piano has **a stool**_'). // But if one **starts** by classing verb V which takes part in such tricky peripheral cases as 'transitive' or 'intransitive', one is certainly being too broad-brush.

Comment: Compare: *Doctors often work Tuesdays.* Can you see that *Tuesdays* is not a direct object?

Comment: They are not direct objects, then are they indirect object? Or adverb phrases?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth May it please you to see “The Grammar of Measure Phrases in English”, John Robert Ross, 1964; “X syntax: A study of Phrase Structure”, Ray Jackendoff, 1977; “Grammar of Measurement”, Roger Schwarzchild, 2002; “Getting the (syntactic) measure of Measure Phrases”, Norbert Carver, 2010. These analyses have their supporters and detractors, but that should be enough to give you a toe-hold into the topic so that you'll be able to use those to find other papers citing them, whether in support or rebuttal.

Comment: Thanks, tchrist. I'll try to get my head round these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrases you quote are adverbial genitives - they have the effect of a modifying prepositional phrase:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive

> Another remnant of the Old English genitive is the adverbial genitive, where the ending s (without apostrophe) forms adverbs of time: **nowadays** *[= now, of a day], closed **Sundays** *[= of a Sunday]*. There is a literary periphrastic form using of, as in **of a summer day**. There are also forms in -ce, from genitives of number and place: once, twice, thrice; whence, hence, thence.

> There is also the "genitive of measure": forms such as "a five-mile journey" and "a ten-foot pole" use what is actually a remnant of the Old English genitive plural which, ending in /a/, had neither the final /s/ nor underwent the foot/feet vowel mutation of the nominative plural. In essence, the underlying forms are "a five of miles (O.E. gen. pl. mīla) journey" and "a ten of feet (O.E. gen. pl. fōta) pole".

Comment: Great, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Measure phrases like *two miles* or *40 hours* are not direct objects, normally

> though there **are** verbs that can take measure objects,
> especially when they stand for quantified noun phrases:
> *He loaded sixteen tons (of number-nine coal).*

Many intransitive clauses have measure phrases after the verb.
These are commonly noun phrases in form, but they're not objects

- *He ran **3 miles** today.*
- *He weighs **way too much** for the surgery.*

These can't be passivized, though

- **3 miles were run by him today*
- **Way too  much for the surgery is weighed by him*

which is a mark of an intransitive clause.

tl;dr - transitivity is not a property of verbs you can look up in a dictionary;
it's a property of **clauses**, including sentences.

Comment: What role do "night shifts" and "3 miles" play in the sentences? Are they adverb phrases? [The syntax of adverbs and adverb phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_adverbs#The_syntax_of_adverbs_and_adverb_phrases) requires a modifier and a head adverb. But I don't think there are any adverb in  "night shifts" and "3 miles".

Comment: @Gqqnbig Measure phrases have a grammar of their very own, but being noun phrases, they always have noun heads not adverb heads. *I ran two miles before breakfast. He weighs two pounds less now. She stood six feet tall. It snowed seven inches overnight. They only arrived twice but departed four times.* Their grammatical role varies (like clausal adjuncts or adjectival complements), but they almost never passivize, which is why you can't say ❌  *Four times were departed by them* or ❌  *No cat or dog has been rained yet today*.

Comment: @tchrist _Almost_ never?!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Right: John gave an example of a measure phrase as clausal object in *He loaded six tons (of number nine coal)*.  That one you can passivize. Contrast *He weighed twelve stone*, which you cannot, with *He weighed twelve stones his sailors had given him for ballast before boarding*, which you can.

Comment: @tchrist Sorry. Not focusing.

Answer (score 1):

**With adverb or noun phrase denoting the length of time or pattern of work** is the significant phrase.

A transitive verb has to have an object. *Long hours* and *night shifts* are not the direct object of *work*, so the fact that they are nouns following it is irrelevant.